# Progressive animation of a sequence of points

Tags: plotting, animation

I have two pieces of code that work.

The first produces a list plot:

```
f[t_] := 10 + 25 t + 20 t^2;
x = Range[0, 10, 1];
y = f[x];
coord = {x[[#]], y[[#]]} & /@ Range[Length[x]];
ListPlot[coord, PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, 20}];
```

[image]

The second generates an animation:

```
SetDirectory["C:\Users\Leandro\Desktop"];
CreateDirectory["Pasta com imagens para GIF"];
SetDirectory["Pasta com imagens para GIF"];
plots = Table[Plot[Sin[x + a], {x, 0, Pi},PlotRange -> {{0, Pi}, {-1.1, 1.1}}], {a, 0, Pi, .1}];
Export["plot001.png", plots, "VideoFrames"];
FileNames[]
```

[image]

How can I combine these two pieces of code to create an animation in which the points of the list plot are appear progressively?

Comment: What do you want to change gradually?  The position of the points?  The appearance of the points?

Comment: Do you want to plot this graph but rise each point's y values? Can you explain it more explicitly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may do this by Plotting multiple figures and show them one by one via using `Manipulate`, `Animate` or `Dynamic`.

```
Animate[
  ListPlot[coord[[;; t]], 
           PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, 20},  
           PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {0, 3000}}], {t, 1, Length@coord, 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

or

```
Dynamic[
  With[{t = Clock[{1, Length[coord], 1}]}, 
  ListPlot[coord[[;; t]], 
           PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, 20},  
           PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {0, 3000}}]
  ]
]
```

[image]